# Detect if the person who liked your Facebook Page was invited by someone else?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Let's say that John sent a request to his friends so they come to your app in your page. John's friend, Paul, clicks on the invitation and comes to your page. When Paul enters the page, I have access to the request object where I can see that John sent the invitation. So far so good.

Now, let's say that Paul likes the page. Do I still have access to that request object so that I can tell that this action was possible thanks to John?

In the case that is not possible using the default like button. Is there an Open Graph method to like your page so that I can create my own button inside the app to make Paul like the page? This way I can send the request object along and I can make the relation myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier if you save the request object containing if the user came by invitation in a cookie and check that after the user has liked your page. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Aha! Talk about thinking outside the box. Will definitely try this and let you know.Thanks!